# Hola estoy intentando instalar datatime en python pero me sale un error

Tags: python, windows

estoy intentando instalar datatime pero me sale el siguiente error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> datatime (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found
> for datatime

que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?, tengo la version 3.10.4 de python, y lo estoy instalando con el comando:

> pip install datatime

Comment: Versión de python? con qué comando lo estás intentando instalar? Por favor, ve a [edit] la pregunta y añades esa info :)

Comment: @Alfabravo listo

Comment: Perdonen si me equivoco, pero no conozco el módulo **datatime**. Lo más cercano es [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) y que ya viene integrado con la distribución de Python. ¿Un error tipográfico?

Comment: si tienes razon perdon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suena muchísimo a que tienes una versión de 32 bits instalada. Acabo de probar exactamente el mismo comando en Python 3.10.2 sin inconvenientes.

Numerosas librerías pueden no tener soporte para versiones 32bit de Python. Asegúrate de usar la versión de 64bit disponible en el [sitio de descarga](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

Recuerda también mantener `pip` al día usando `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Por último, asegúrate de estar usando la versión de Python que supones que estás usando, ejecutando `python -V`

Comment: si, tengo la version de 64bits

Comment: Respuesta editada porque está aún más sospechosa ;)

Comment: me equivoque, no era datatime era datetime

Answer (score 1):

gente ya no respondan, era datetime no datatime XD